# Firebird FK on delete cascade and on update cascade trigger order

Tags: constraints, replication, firebird, cascading-deletes

Anyone has idea why Firebird update and delete foreign key rule, work in a inverse logical?

When you changes some data and it is a FK, the Firebird behavior :

- First: delete master
- After: delete details

When my guess that correct behavior would be:

- First: delete details
- After: delete master

This a big problem when you try to replicate the data to another database in runtime.

Answer (score 2):

It is the delete on master that causes the cascading delete. On an implementation level this is handled by a system trigger on the table, therefor the delete on the master has to happen first, and the delete from details is the result of that.

I don't know how you are replicating the data, but you might want to check if you are using `BEFORE` or `AFTER` triggers to do this (however I don't know if changing `BEFORE` to `AFTER` would change firing order to detail-master).

For more detailed information on implementation and limitation, you might want to post a question on the *firebird-devel* mailinglist. There are people following that list who have also built replication software, and the core Firebird developers might provide more detailed info.